# How to mix a list from a given list that includes sorted sublists in O(N)

Tags: list, algorithm, sorting, merge, time-complexity

Assume that we have the initial list as follows:

```
initial=[{"A",1}, {"A",2}, {"A",3}, {"B",5}, {"B",7}, {"C",6}, {"C",8}, {"D",4}]
```

which is a list of T.
We have an entity like; `class T{ string Title;  int Id;}`
The initial list is ordered by Title then Id and we know it at the beginning.

I want to mix the list so that we have a result list at the end as follows:

```
result=[{"A",1}, {"B",5}, {"C",6}, {"D",4}, {"A",2}, {"B",7}, {"C",8}, {"A",3}]
```

Sublists in the initial list are:

```
{"A",1}, {"A",2}, {"A",3}

{"B",5}, {"B",7}

{"C",6}, {"C",8}

{"D",4}
```

Original problem can be like this:
Write a function that takes list of T whose elemets are ordered by Title then Id and return a new list of T that mixes the T entities in a way that one entity from each title at a time. Function should round around every Title and place one T entity from each title(rounding from A to D in ascending), continue on like this until all the T entities are placed in the result list.

Is there a solution in O(N) where N is the size of the given list?

Comment: I am trying to have the result list from the initial list in O(N). In terms of picking, yes it is retrieved in O(1). I just wanted to explain, in our example, we have 4 sublists in the initial list which are already ordered. Result list is currently empty, assume a new list of T. So i think my algorithm should get A-1 and put it to result list then get B-5 and put it to the result list .. Picking was my way to solution, but if you have better approach, i would like to hear

Answer (score 0):

- first of all let's count for each title how many times it appears in the initial list. We can do that by one pass through the elements and increase a counter whenever we have element equal to the last element, and when we reach a new element we push the current value of the counter to a new list and reset the counter to 1. So at the end of this step we will have a list that looks like this(for your example: Count=[3,2,2,1]).
- Let's perform cumulative sum on this list and store the values in another list of pairs, were the first element of each pair is the cumulative sum and the second element is initialized with zero. so now we have Pref=[(3,0),(5.0),(7,0),(8,0)].
- Now let's loop over this list, if we are now in index *i* of this list we will add the element at index *pref[i-1].first + pref[i].second* from the initial array to the new array, and increase the value in *pref[i].second* by one. after we finish processing the current element we copy the new value of the pair to a new list, unless *pref[i].second = pref[i].first*, then we don't copy it to the new list. In the next iteration we process elements from the new list in the same manner.

The first loop to compute **Count** and **Pref** requires O(N) time, where *N* is the total number of elements in the array. In the next step the total number of times that we need to iterate over an element and copy it is N times, because each element of *pref* will be processed and copied an amount of time equal to its value, and the total sum of values is *N* the initial total number of elements. So the run time of the whole algorithm is O(N).